# Adding a controller to an element directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When adding a controller to a element directive, for example:

```
.directive('hello', function() {

   return {     
     restrict: 'E',
     replace: true,
     transclude: true,
     template: '<div class="hello" ng-transclude></div>'
   };

});
```

I'm unable to access the scope of the controller:

```
.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope) {  
  $scope.hello = "Hello World";
});


<hello ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Directive</h1>

  <p>{{ hello }}</p>
</hello>
```

In this case `{{ hello }}` is undefined. The directive doesn't create a child nor an isolated scope. I also tried accessing the property with `{{ $parent.hello }}`.

What is happening here?

I created a CodePen to demonstrate this behaviour: http://codepen.io/jviotti/pen/ktpbE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs...

transclude makes the contents of a directive with this option have access to the scope outside of the directive rather than inside.

Therefore you need to move the ng-controller="HelloCtrl" declaration to an element higher up in scope.

Here is your CodePen fixed http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjKHG

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this without putting the controller in an element higher in the scope?

Comment: You could just assign the controller in the directive definition using the controller property